# How i want to convert int to str

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to combines the values of the important columns into a single string but one of the columns is a integer. And really don't know where to put the str() code to convert the int to string. so this is my code:

```
#create function to combine the values of the important columns into a single string
def get_important_features(data):
  important_features = []
  for i in range(0, data.shape[0]):
    important_features.append(data['Location'][i]+' '+str(data['Price'])[i]+' '+data['Property Type'][i]+' '+data['Furnishing'][i])

  return important_features


**#create a column to hold the combined strings**
df['important_features'] = get_important_features(df)

#show the data

df.head(3)
```

**This is the error output:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ef130dbef96b> in <module>()
      1 #create a column to hold the combined strings
----> 2 df['important_features'] = get_important_features(df)
      3 
      4 #show the data
      5 


<ipython-input-15-fda6e7b86a60> in get_important_features(data)
      3   important_features = []
      4   for i in range(0, data.shape[0]):
----> 5     important_features.append(data['Location'][i]+' '+str(data['Price'])[i]+' '+data['Property Type'][i]+' '+data['Furnishing'][i])
      6 
      7   return important_features

TypeError: must be str, not float
```

Comment: assuming you're working with a pandas data frame, most likely you don't need  the for-loop at all.

Comment: `str(number)` will create a string from a number but in this case I would look into using f-strings.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
important_features.append(data['Location'][i]+' '+str(data['Price'][i])+' '+data['Property Type'][i]+' '+data['Furnishing'][i])
```

only change is

> `str(data['Price'][i])`  paranthesis

Answer (score 0):

Thank u guys. i have solve the answer. thank u for your idea everyone

i edit this line:

```
important_features.append(data['Location'][i]+' '+str(data['Price'][i])+' '+data['Property Type'][i]+' '+data['Furnishing'][i])
```

and change like this:

```
important_features.append(str(data['Location'][i])+' '+str(data['Price'][i])+' '+str(data['Property Type'][i])+' '+str(data['Furnishing'][i]) )
```